# Выбрать все записи, где встречается '7'

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mysql

Помогите правильно сделать выборку из БД.
У меня есть поле `VARCAR`, в нём хранится такое значение: '5,26,7'.

Как выбрать все записи, где встречается '7'?

Пробовал `LIKE'`ом, но получается немного не так. Допустим, что надо  '7', то пишу `LIKE '%7%'`, но `mysql` вернёт все записи, где присутствует эта цифра включая '17', '27'. У меня хранятся максимум двузначные числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навскидку, без проверки — `SELECT ... WHERE column REGEXP '(^|,)[[:space:]]*7[[:space:]]*(,|$)'`

Правда, такой запрос выглядит дико и если он будет выполняться больше, чем раз в жизни, то, пожалуй, стоит подумать, не нужно ли нормализовать базу.

Другой вариант [поиска чисел в списке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674011/mysql-check-if-numbers-are-in-a-comma-separated-list), найденный на SO — `... WHERE find_in_set('7', column) > 0`.

MySQL под руками нет, проверить, к сожалению, не на чем.

---

Еще на SO упоминается вариант `... WHERE 7 IN (column)`, но он **неверен**. Как я понял, так [IN использовать **нельзя**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4156063/116546), т.к.:

```
column IN ('1,2,3') ≡ column IN (CAST('1,2,3' AS INT)) ≡ column IN (1)
```

Т.е. результаты будут частично правдоподобны, но ошибочны.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Проверил первые два варианта - работает. Применил 2 вариант, т.к. самый короткий.

Comment: @Idaho37: Нашел, пишут, что вариант с [IN против find_in_set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in) неверен. Извините за дезинформацию. Используйте `find_in_set`.

Comment: Я понял, что IN со строкой не работает например IN('2,52,4'), но так IN(2,52,4) всё ищет. А у меня строка так что заметил что ищет в том случае, если искомое число стоит в начале строки, например 2 IN('2,52,4'). А первый вариант хорошо работает. попробую третий.

Comment: Да, find_in_set тоже правильно ищет. Спасибо.

Comment: Можно значительно упростить регулярное выражение. Я приведу его в PCRE, переделать его в POSIX дело техники.  

    \b7\b

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '7,26,17' REGEXP '^7';
```

Comment: Не факт, что требуемое число будет стоять в начале.